# jQuery Mobile: about the page container ($.mobile.pageContainer)

Tags: jquery-mobile

$.mobile.pageContainer refers to the element that contains other virtual pages. It is set to `<body>`. So I assume that it can be changed. Indeed, some JQM methods (changePage) lets you specify non-default page container for a page. The JQM docs are lacking the necessary details. So my questions are:

1. Can you change the default page container in markup/code? How?
2. What are the reasons to have a page container other than `<body>`?
3. Does it mean that there can be multiple page containers with some "pages" residing in one page container and other "pages" residing in other containers? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: well, I've done some tests on loading pages into a different container. It looks like they are intended to load extra pages which you want to show only once as they vanish once you leave them back to original container. Also, if you're using next/back or swipe left/right they wont appear in the sequence of pages.

Answer (score 3):

1 You can place your page divs within a container element in markup.

2 I use ASP.Net Webforms which requires a FORM element, so sometimes I add my jQM pages to a top level FORM instead of the body allowing me to use ASP.Net controls within my separate pages while sharing the same FORM element.

3 I think you need to keep all pages within the same container, otherwise links between pages break.  Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lt7cs/1/)** with 2 pages in a container linking to eachother. Try putting them in separate containers and you will see the linking stop working.

```
<div id="PageContainer1">
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
           <h1>My page 1</h1> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"> <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Go to Page 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- insert separate container here 
</div>
<div id="PageContainer2">
-->
    <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My page 2</h1> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"> <a href="#page1" data-role="button">Go to Page 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments, you can certainly navigate to pages in other containers via changePage, just the standard href="#page2" links break.

```
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {"pageContainer": $("#Container2")});
```

I am not sure of a use case for having separate containers, perhaps code organization?

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that a URL shortener was used to avoid the restrictions on posting a fiddle without code in the question? External sites can go dark at any time and it is hoped that these questions will be of long term use

Comment: Richard, I could not seem to add code with the auto-numbered list, it just treated it as HTML. I have updated the answer removing the auto-numbering and then inserting the code. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, JQM sets the $.mobile.pageContainer to the parent of the first [data-role='page'] it encounters. However, it is still unclear why JQM navigating methods (changePage, loadPage) let you specify another non-default page container.

Comment: you can change pages in different page containers http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/37nSK/

Comment: @Omar That's what I am talking about. These methods are a proof that JQM supports multiple page containers. But nobody can explain why.

Comment: +1 for the hint that pages have to be in the same same container (and they cannot reside on a different div level) for the linking to work